# How to implement data transfer between the coroutine and the main environment?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want an asynchronous "magic box" that will do something, return some value, wait for a response from the outside and keep working. I sketched such a variant, but it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

```
import asyncio


async def pipeline():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    for i in range(2):
        yield i
        n = yield
        print(f"{n=}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
    pl = pipeline()
    async for i in pl:
        print(f"{i=}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        await pl.asend(-i)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I was expecting to get

```
i=0
n=0
i=1
n=-1
```

But i got

```
i=0
n=None
i=1
n=None
```

How can I change the code to make it work correctly?

Comment: I found out that it will work correctly if you swap `yield i` and `n = yield`. But I don't understand why. I would appreciate a reply with a detailed breakdown of the problem

Answer (score -1):

The same `yield` statement that will make a value (`i`) available outside your generator is the one that takes in whatever was "sent" from the outside: you do not have to write two "yields":

```
async def pipeline():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    for i in range(2):
        n = yield i  # < this line sends "i" to the outside and resolves to whatever value was sent here.
        print(f"{n=}")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Comment: This looks correct, but it actually prints an unexpected result: i=0
n=0
n=None

Comment: That is beause you are a;so using the same object to which you `send` values in the `for`loop: the two things wont work together (unless using a carefull mixture of two `yield`s as you had in your code, but that is really coupled code.

Use a while loop, and use the return value of `.send` itself to retrieve the next value from the generator - check the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send